# Mechanism like CUDA streams in Xeon Phi?

Tags: stream, icc, xeon-phi

I am new to work with Xeon Phi Co-processor and my question is:

Does exists a mechanism like CUDA streams in Xeon Phi ???

Comment: What programming language / paradigm are you referring to? Xeon Phi is a piece of hardware while CUDA streams are some programming language features... So both are kind of hard to compare. Anyway, I guess that OpenCL queues for example might address your question. But they probably are not the only "solutions" for your "problem".

Comment: @Gilles I am using c language and icc compiler. Is it possible to use OpenCL with icc?

Comment: [Yes it is](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/jumpstart-tutorial)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  The Intel Manycore Platform Software Stack (MPSS) provides **hStreams**, which are designed to be similar to the CUDA streams model.

There is a [chapter](http://lotsofcores.com/hStreams) in *High Performance Parallel Programming Pearls II* on hStreams, which you can preview in [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=MUZ0CAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA286&ots=nBWQPQe4lo&dq=xeon%20phi%20hstreams&pg=PA271#v=onepage&q=xeon%20phi%20hstreams&f=false).

I can't find any detailed documentation on Intel's website, but the [release notes](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-many-integrated-core/topic/532271) say that you can find PDFs in the MPSS distribution, which should be on any Intel Xeon Phi coprocessor system.

BSC has detailed documentation of hStreams [here](https://pm.bsc.es/content/hstreams-doc).

Comment: Do you know any example about hStreams??

Comment: Please see the BSC link in my answer. It has a number of examples.

Answer (score 2):

That's right, hStreams essentially covers the key features of CUDA Streams and OpenCL, in that several CUDA Streams and OpenCL apps have been ported to hStreams.  Users of hStreams, like the OmpSs folks at Barcelona Supercomputing assessed that hStreams was easier to use than CUDA Streams, and offered better support for synchronization, required fewer unique APIs, and fewer lines of code.

For some more documentation, please see http://lotsofcores.com/hStreams, which you can also find a link of where to download MPSS and a blog that offers a few highlights of its features, including hStreams.
Once you've installed hStreams, look in /usr/share/doc/hStreams.